# Implementation of the 'set' method for a linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, implementation, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement the set method where you pass in the position in a linked list that you want and the value and the set function adds that value into the position specified in the linked list. I have implemented the set function but for some reason The last element disappears in my implementation. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. I would appreciate any expert eyes that will see what I am missing.

```
/**
 * A basic singly linked list implementation.
 */
public class SinglyLinkedList<E> implements Cloneable, Iterable<E>, List<E> {
    //---------------- nested Node class ----------------

    /**
     * Node of a singly linked list, which stores a reference to its
     * element and to the subsequent node in the list (or null if this
     * is the last node).
     */
    private static class Node<E> {
       E value;
       Node<E> next;
       public Node(E e) 
       { 
           value = e; 
           next = null; 
       } 
    }
    
    //----------- end of nested Node class -----------

    // instance variables of the SinglyLinkedList
    private Node<E> head = null; // head node of the list (or null if empty)

    private int size = 0; // number of nodes in the list

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
    }              // constructs an initially empty list

    // access methods

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the linked list.
     *
     * @return number of elements in the linked list
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    /**
     * Adds an element to the end of the list.
     *
     * @param e the new element to add
     */
    public void addLast(E e) {
        // TODO
    }
    /**
     * Tests whether the linked list is empty.
     *
     * @return true if the linked list is empty, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Node<E> a = head;
        if(i<=this.size()) {
            int count = 0;
            while(count < i) {
                count ++;
                a = a.next;
            }
            return a.value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int i, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Node<E> current = head;
        Node<E> setNode = new Node<E>(e);
        if(i==0) {
            this.addFirst(e);
        }
        else if(i==this.size){
            this.addLast(e);
        }
        else {
            for(int j=0; current != null && j < (i-1);j++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            Node<E> temp = current.next;
            current.next = setNode;
            setNode.next = temp;
        }
        return setNode.value;
        }
    
    

    

   

    // update methods

    /**
     * Adds an element to the front of the list.
     *
     * @param e the new element to add
     */
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        Node<E> first = new Node<>(e);
        first.next = this.head;
        this.head = first;
        this.size++;
    }

   

    
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO
        return false;   // if we reach this, everything matched successfully
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public SinglyLinkedList<E> clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Produces a string representation of the contents of the list.
     * This exists for debugging purposes only.
     * @return 
     */
    public String toString() {
        for(int i=0;i<this.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(this.get(i));
        }
        return "end of Linked List";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            SinglyLinkedList <Integer> ll =new SinglyLinkedList <Integer>();
            ll.addFirst(5);
            ll.addFirst(4);
            ll.addFirst(3);
            ll.addFirst(2);
            ll.set(1,0);
            System.out.println(ll);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add `addLast` implementation? It is missing in the above code. Also, you are not updating the size inside the `set` methods `for` loop

Comment: Yes, turns out the problem was incrementing the size. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is planned to do with `set` method. The way it is implemented now, it behaves more like `insert`, meaning that it will add new node, bit it does not increase the total count of elements (`size`).

It the `set` method is changing the value of the node, which name indicates, then this part is wrong:

```
else {
    for(int j=0; current != null && j < (i-1);j++) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    Node<E> temp = current.next;
    current.next = setNode;
    setNode.next = temp;
}
```

It should replace the value instead of adding the new one:

```
else {
    for(int j=0; current != null && j < (i-1);j++) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.value=e
}
```

Also, it looks like the index `i` is 1-based, while everything else is 0 based. I didn't check the code above, but the concept should be like shown.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

1. `addLast` method is missing in the code
2. The error could be there too

### Known cause

This code is not incrementing the `size` inside the `set` method's `for` loop.The `size` is incremented in `addLast`(possibly) and `addFirst` and not incremented in other case (final `else` part)